# SupportMapFragment and onMapReady

Tags: android, google-maps, supportmapfragment

Hee Guys,

I've been searching for a few hours now and tried different things, most of them I already had included. I hope you guys can help with something I'm apparently not seeing.

I have a SupportMapFragment inside my fragment for Maps. I used to have this working but for some reason it just crashes now with a nullpointer. After searching for hours and reading some more documentation I found out I use a deprecated way so I tried using the advised one : onMapReady. However it doesn't recognise the function even when I'm using

```
com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
```

Here is my xml with the fragment :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayoutMainAct"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/map_overlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

And here is the code starting in OnViewCreated :

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    if(GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(MainActivity.getContext()) == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        initMap();
        if (locations != null) {
            addMarkers();
        }
        moveMapToCuracao();
    }
}

public void initMap() {
    final SupportMapFragment myMAPF = (SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(mapView);
    myMAPF.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            mGoogleMap = googleMap;

            mGoogleMap.setPadding(50, 0, 0, 0);
            mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mGoogleMap
                    .setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new OnMyLocationChangeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            GeomagneticField field = new GeomagneticField(
                                    (float) location.getLatitude(),
                                    (float) location.getLongitude(),
                                    (float) location.getAltitude(), System
                                    .currentTimeMillis());

                            // getDeclination returns degrees
                            mDeclination = field.getDeclination();
                        }

                    });

            if (locations != null) {
                addMarkers();
            }
            moveMapToCuracao();
        }
    });
}
```

**UPDATE : Updated code thanks to Eugen**

But stil crashes on getMapAsync() with a NullPointerException.

Comment: 1. Are you sure you want a map fragment inside another fragment? 2. Use `getMapAsync`, do your map init in the callback and don't keep `mGoogleMap` because it's not safe to use outside of `getMapAsync` anyway.

Comment: Where to use the getMapAsync then? And how should I do it otherwise?

Comment: Use `getMapAsync` instead of `getMap` see [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment.html#getMapAsync%28com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback%29). You could extend `SupportMapFragment`.

Comment: That is the problem. I can't it wont recognise it as stated above. But i'll give the SupportMapFragment a go.

Comment: Do you use Google Play Services library at least v6.5.87 ? `getMapAsync` was introduced just then

Comment: I was using the 6.1.+ just changed it and it is now working. Thanks!

Comment: Updated the code, but still crashes. See updated Question please. Might give an answer next to prevent long comments here. Or start a chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68805/discussion-between-eugen-pechanec-and-jordi-sipkens).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The map fragment is part of a layout you inflate to another fragment (let's call it parent). The inflated fragment becomes a child fragment NOT of the activity BUT of the parent fragment. You have to ask the parent fragment's child fragment manager:

```
final SupportMapFragment myMAPF = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(mapView);
```